# Phase Response Measurement

Tags: frequency-measurement, phase

I have built a few analog filters (LPF, HPF, etc), after the filters, there are some amplifiers, MUX, and it goes to a ADC. For this project I am suppose to have as much of a linear system as possible. So I am wondering how I can measure the phase response of this system (0-60KHz, from the input, which could be a coil or some type of sensor to the ADC) with a 200MHz scope, and some cheap function generators (cannot afford spectrum/network analyzers) so that I can try to build lattice filters or use the DSP afterwards to try and fix the phase response.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Is your waveform pure square or sinusoide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use an oscilloscope, with inputs for both the input and output of the block you need the phase response for to measure the time difference between peaks of the input and peaks of the output for input sine waves of various frequencies.  Then, multiply time delay divided by the period by 360 deg/cylcle to get the phase in degrees.

Many scopes, even inexpensive scopes, let you use averaging to get better measurements in the presence of noisy inputs and outputs.  You can also adjust scope sensitivity and the time base to let you capture the most accuracy in your measurement. For that matter, many scopes these days have a phase measurement option in their measurement menu.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I am wondering, with a noisy function generator, wouldn't the phase response be inaccurate considering the signal I see on the scope of for the function generator has jitter. Also is there a more effective way to test this without me manually stepping each frequency?

Comment: Also, since some of the filters are high order, the theoretical phase response says that it would be more than 360 degrees phase delay, which would mean that this method cannot catch say a 720 degree phase delay?

Comment: The effective way to automate this is a spectrum analyzer, but it sounds like this isn't an option for you.

Comment: Re: your second comment, no method can measure a 360° or 720° phase because they look identical to a 0° phase.

Comment: @user8481 many scopes, even inexpensive scopes, let you use averaging to get better measurements in the presence of noisy inputs and outputs.  You can also adjust scope sensitivity and the time base to let you capture the most accuracy in your measurement. For that matter, many scopes these days have a phase measurement option in their measurement menu.  No technique you use will let you capture phases beyond 360 degrees.  Some systems will want to place phase between 180 and -180.  Pick your tangent wrapping problem, and deal with it!